# Different Images in JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx

My project works but I want to little upgrade for this.
And I have a question.
How add to this project image , that would be different it every if?
I tried using ImageView but I don't know how properly do this.
Please give some advice.

```
package sample;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;


public class Controller {
    @FXML
    private Label label;
    @FXML
    private TextField weightText;
    @FXML
    private TextField heightText;
    @FXML
    private Label label2;

    @FXML
    public void count() {

        double bmi = 0;
        int bmi2 = 0;
        double weight = 0;
        double height = 0;
        label2.setText("");


        try {
            weight = Double.parseDouble(weightText.getText());
            height = Double.parseDouble(heightText.getText());

            if (weight > 0 && wzrost > 0) {
                bmi = (weight / (height* height)) * 100;
                bmi2 = (int) bmi;
                bmi = (double) bmi2 / 100;
                if (bmi > 30) {
                    label.setText("Your'e too fat. Your bmi is:  " + bmi);
                } else if (bmi > 25 && bmi < 30) {
                    label.setText("Little to much weight. Your bmi is: "+bmi);
                } else if (bmi > 18.5 && bmi < 25) {
                    label.setText("Great shape. Your bmi is: " + bmi);
                } else {
                    label.setText("Your'e to skinny.Your bmi is:" + bmi);
                }
            } else {
                label.setText("Wrong values");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            label2.setText("Use dot");
            label.setText("Wrong values!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify what you are asking. Picture where? What is "different it every if"?

Comment: in this place :  if (bmi > 30) {
                    label.setText("Your'e too fat. Your bmi is:  " + bmi);
                } else if (bmi > 25 && bmi < 30) {
                    label.setText("Little to much weight. Your bmi is: "+bmi);
                } else if (bmi > 18.5 && bmi < 25) {
                    label.setText("Great shape. Your bmi is: " + bmi);
                } else {
                    label.setText("Your'e to skinny.Your bmi is:" + bmi);    
besides the text, i want to display pictures

Comment: Where do you want to put that picture ?

Comment: What is your scene structure? `ImageView` is a `Node` and can be placed in a scene the same way other `Node`s can, but `Label`s and `TextField`s are probably not the correct place to add an image.

Comment: Show a fxml file?

Comment: @yach Edit your code and add your fxml file where you want to put the image

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you want to add the image to, so I'm going to assume it's going to be contained in some kind of `Pane` object (called `YOUR_PANE`), but this could be anything else that extends `Node`, such as an `AnchorPane` or `VBox`. In the end it's something that will be contained in the `Scene` that is being used by your current `Stage`

First you'll need a reference to the image you want to load, which can be done using a `InputStream`:

```
//Creating an image 
Image image = new Image(new FileInputStream("PATH_TO_IMAGE"));
```

Using this image you can create an `ImageView`, which is a JavaFX image container (this is using some example values).

```
  //Setting the image view 
  ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image); 

  //Setting the position of the image 
  imageView.setX(50); 
  imageView.setY(25); 

  //setting the fit height and width of the image view 
  imageView.setFitHeight(455); 
  imageView.setFitWidth(500);
```

In your example, you want to change the image depending on the result of your `If` statements, so you can change the image path like so:

```
String imagePath = "C://defaultImage.jpg";

try {
        weight = Double.parseDouble(weightText.getText());
        height = Double.parseDouble(heightText.getText());

        if (weight > 0 && wzrost > 0) {
            bmi = (weight / (height* height)) * 100;
            bmi2 = (int) bmi;
            bmi = (double) bmi2 / 100;
            if (bmi > 30) {
                label.setText("Your'e too fat. Your bmi is:  " + bmi);
                imagePath = "C://image1.jpg"
            } else if (bmi > 25 && bmi < 30) {
                label.setText("Little to much weight. Your bmi is: "+bmi);
                imagePath = "C://image2.jpg"
            } else if (bmi > 18.5 && bmi < 25) {
                label.setText("Great shape. Your bmi is: " + bmi);
                imagePath = "C://image3.jpg"
            } else {
                label.setText("Your'e to skinny.Your bmi is:" + bmi);
                imagePath = "C://image4.jpg"
            }
        } else {
            label.setText("Wrong values");
        }

        Image image = new Image(new FileInputStream(imagePath));
        //Setting the image view 
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image); 

        //Setting the position of the image 
        imageView.setX(50); 
        imageView.setY(25); 

        //setting the fit height and width of the image view 
        imageView.setFitHeight(455); 
        imageView.setFitWidth(500);

        //Adding the image to the pane you want it to be displayed in
        YOUR_PANE.getChildren().add(imageView);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        label2.setText("Use dot");
        label.setText("Wrong values!");
    }
```

This assumes that you're creating your GUI entirely in code, but the same effect can be achieved by using FXML files, which has lots of benefits ([here's what Orcale has to say](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/fxml_get_started/why_use_fxml.htm)). One advantage is that you can use a tool called [Scene Builder](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/javafxscenebuilder-info-2157684.html), which lets you create a GUI using a drag & drop interface.

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer the question according to what I understood :

You need to add an `ImageView` to your **Controller** (**and** to your fxml file of course):

```
@FXML 
private ImageView imageView;
```

your `if` statements become :

```
Image image;
      if (weight > 0 && wzrost > 0) {
                    bmi = (weight / (height* height)) * 100;
                    bmi2 = (int) bmi;
                    bmi = (double) bmi2 / 100;
                    if (bmi > 30) {
                          image = new Image("TooFat.png");
                          label.setText("Your'e too fat. Your bmi is:  " + bmi);
                    } else if (bmi > 25 && bmi < 30) {
                          image = new Image("LittleTooMuch.png");
                          label.setText("Little to much weight. Your bmi is: "+bmi);
                    } else if (bmi > 18.5 && bmi < 25) {
                          image = new Image("GreatShape.png");
                          label.setText("Great shape. Your bmi is: " + bmi);
                    } else {
                          image = new Image("Skinny.png");
                          label.setText("You're to skinny.Your bmi is:" + bmi);
                    }
                } else {
                    image = new Image("WrongValues.png");
                    label.setText("Wrong values");
                }
    }
    imageView.setImage(image);
```

**PS : Put the images in your project and change the path accordingly** 
Hope this answers your question